# How to correctly pass the generator to the function parameters of ThreadPoolExecutor Executor.map()？

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, python-multithreading

In the following program, I have two questions I want to ask. The first question is, why do I need to traverse the `generator` before calling the function when I use the `thread pool` to pass the `generator` to the function? The second question is how to use the correct method to pass the `generator` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor Executor.map` function. The following program exits directly after traversing the files in the `path` directory without calling the `req` function

My final catalog is to read a lot of pictures to `base64` encoding, and then use `multiple threads` to send `HTTP requests` and get the results. If the method I use is not the most efficient, please recommend me some efficient and excellent methods,Thanks in advance

```
import json
import requests
import base64
import os
from itertools import repeat
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor



def img_to_base64(img_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(img_path):
        for pic in files:
            if pic.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')):
                img = os.path.join(root, pic)
                with open(img, 'rb') as f:
                    bs64 = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
                yield img,bs64 

def req(host, img, bs64):
    url = f'http://{host}/demo/'
    body = {"requests": [
                    {
                        "resource": {
                            "base64": bs64
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body))
    print(img, r)


def run(host,path):
    base64s = img_to_base64(path)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
        ret = list(ex.map(req, repeat(host), base64s))
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run('192.168.10.44','/data/'）
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to traverse the generator first? What do you change to make the code work?

Comment: Also, why did you tag this both 3.x and 2.7? `concurrent.futures` isn't provided, as a built-in at least, in Python 2. And a minor note on your import: `concurrent.futures.thread` is not a documented name. The correct documented import would be `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

So ThreadPoolExecutor map method takes an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map)

Passing a generator object to `map` traverses that iterable.

There's a way around this behaviour, but it is a little bit of a hacky method  - call that generator method from within a list, which will make your executor accept is as a generator object, instead of the next yielded item

```py
base64s = [img_to_base64(path)]
```

Edit:

This will only work with a mutable iterator such as a List (a tuple for instance, will not get the same result)

This relates to the way we simulate pointers in python, RealPython has a [nice explanation](https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/#simulating-pointers-in-python) for this specific subject.